# building osmand with "ant debug" gives error

Tags: android, ant, build, osmdroid

I have checked out latest Osmand source code from here 
and followed all the steps from here

now i am trying to build apk through ant with command ant debug but it fails

i executed following commands :

```
myname@myname-VirtualBox:~/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd$ ant -f build.xml
which gives output as
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

after when i try

```
myname@myname-VirtualBox:~/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd$ ant debug
```

it fails with following log in the end :

```
-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/moonshooter/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/moonshooter/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:

BUILD FAILED
/home/myname/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd/build.xml:27: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/myname/dev/osmand/android/OsmAnd/build.xml:28: Missing attribute libraryRFileRefid

Total time: 18 seconds
```

the 27th and 28th lines in xml are

```
<do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources...">
                    <aapt executable="${aapt}" command="package" versioncode="${version.code}"versionname="${version.name}" debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}" manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"assets="${asset.absolute.dir}" androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}" apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}" resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}" libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages" previousBuildType="$`enter code here`{build.last.target}"buildType="${build.target}" ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
```

and here is the whole file http://pastebin.com/Dv20iT8r

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: I think that error returned by ant is very clear - `<aapt/>` task requires `libraryRFileRefid` attribute to work propertly.

Comment: i am not good at ant, where the library should be? installed in the system or it needs some folder?

Comment: it says "Missing attribute libraryRFileRefid" where it should be defined and where it needs the attribute?

Comment: Attribute should be added like this `<aapt libraryRFileRefi="" ... />`. I can't find aapt documentation so I can't help you. Do you know where can I find it?

Answer (score 4):

Just need to add this property **libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"** in **aapt** tag

```
<do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources...">
            <aapt executable="${aapt}" command="package" versioncode="${version.code}" versionname="${version.name}" debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}" manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}" assets="${asset.absolute.dir}" androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}" apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}" nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}" resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}" resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}" libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path" libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path" libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages" previousBuildType="${build.last.target}" buildType="${build.target}" ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
                <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
```